# How to remove the footer on refreshing the listview in android

Tags: android

I want to remove the footer which i have added in my listview after refreshing the listview.
I also may need to add later in the future execution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show us what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem in doing that you just have to add the footer normally as you do and then call

```
mListView.removeFooterView(footer_view);
```

when you need to remove the Footer. Just make sure that when you have to re-add footer again you add it and then again `setAdapter` of your ListView.

Because as well know,

> NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can
>   wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header
>   and footer views.

Comment: i tried earlier with the same code but got force closes... May be i have not used it at the right place....... Anyway once again thanks for your reply